How can I respond back on same gin context if response to be sent is received on some other endpoint
So, I have to handle sync call in async way.
My go microservice using gin context receives request on /req endpoint, and I have to send it to some other microservice say B, after performing validations, which will give me acknowledgement that it received the request.
Upon receiving request B will perform operation and respond to my microservice at /resp endpoint.
Now the response which came from B has to be sent back to the service which sent request on /req.
Note: I have to write back response on same context from which I initially got request at /req.
My implementation: I was able to achieve this using channels and sync map but with this approach, there is a major scalability issue, if I scale my service to multiple instances, response from B can come on any instance, and that instance will not be having that channel and map, as it is specific to particular instance.
So I need a solution, considering

Session affinity cannot be used.
initial service cannot be changed, so I have to handle this.
Please let me know a solution which can help.


Consider using an orchestration framework instead of dealing with the low-level details of routing and state management directly. Here is how the solution looks like using temporal.io open source framework:

Implement a workflow that invokes an activity.
The workflow and activity can be either colocated in service B. Or B can host only the activity and the initial service can host the workflow.
Then call ExecuteWorkflow and wait for its completion synchronously from the handler. The routing of the response as well as all the other complexities of resiliently brokering a long running interaction in the presence of various types of failures would be handled by the framework.


What you describe is a reverse proxy or API gateway. That has little to do with synchronous or asynchronous processing.
Instead of sending request and responses from A to B back and forth (with the request on A being synchronous either way and hence being prone to a timeout), simply pass the request directly to B after doing your checks.
It is simple enough: You fire up a httputil.ReverseProxy using httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy for each backend micro service and do the required checks using a middleware - a http.Handler which may execute arbitrary code before passing the (modified) request to the next handler in the chain and which may execute other code after said handler returned:
func mySuperMiddleWare(greeting string, next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
       log.Print("hello, ")
       next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
       log.Println(greeting)
    })
}

So basically, for a single backend service, your complete code could look something like this:
package main

import (
    "context"
    "flag"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

var path = "/rev"
var bind = ":8080"
var endpoint = "http://localhost:9090"

func init() {
    flag.StringVar(&path, "path", path, "Path to listen for requests to reverse proxy")
    flag.StringVar(&endpoint, "endpoint", endpoint, "Endpoint to reverse proxy")
    flag.StringVar(&bind, "bind", bind, "Bind address of reverse proxy server")
}

// All we need in this setup is a simple middleware
// doing our checks and then passing the request to the next handler
// in the chain - in this case the reverse proxy.
func checks(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        log.Println("Checking...")
        if time.Now().Day()%2 == 0 {
            http.Error(w, "Not allowed", http.StatusForbidden)
            return
        }
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    u, err := url.Parse(endpoint)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to parse endpoint: %v", err)
    }

    // Of course, you can use multiple reverse proxies
    // for different endpoints listening on different paths
    p := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(u)

    // We strip the path prefix from the request URL
    // do our checks and then pass the request to the reverse proxy
    http.Handle(path, http.StripPrefix(path, checks(p)))

    // Create a context which will be "Done" when either SIGINT or SIGTERM is received
    ctx, cancel := signal.NotifyContext(context.Background(), syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    // Free up resources when done
    defer cancel()

    srv := &http.Server{Addr: bind}

    // Fire up the server
    go func() {
        if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != nil && err != http.ErrServerClosed {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to start server: %v", err)
        }
    }()

    // Wait for the context to be "Done" - aka SIGINT or SIGTERM were received
    <-ctx.Done()
    log.Println("Shutting down...")

    // Create a context with a timeout of 5 seconds
    // srv.Shutdown will obey this timeout
    shutdownContext, cancelShutdown := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    defer cancelShutdown()
    srv.Shutdown(shutdownContext)
    log.Println("Shutdown complete")
}


But microservice sends instant acknowledgement and actual response is received on some other endpoint, moreover I need to write response on same context from which I got request. So how will this solve my problem.

@AmritSingh You can’t have the cake and eat it. Gin contexts are request scoped, and when the request is completed, it is gone. Same goes for a timeout on the client side. No matter how hard you want it to behave differently. You could try to embed nats, send the request to the backend and have a callback publish to a topic “responses.”. This does not solve the client timeout issue, though. No matter how you view it, what you try seems to result in a brittle service under ideal circumstances.
